# Asp Net Web API ADFS and WIF authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-identity, adfs3.0

Is it possible to use two different authentication "paths" in the same Web API,
i.e have one authenticate using Active Directory Federation Services(ADFS) and one authenticate against Identity Framework?

Is as simple as doing the following?

```
pubilc void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{ 
    oauthauthorizationserveroptions oauthserveroptions = new oauthauthorizationserveroptions()
    {
       allowinsecurehttp = true,
       tokenendpointpath = new pathstring("/token"),
       accesstokenexpiretimespan = timespan.fromdays(30),
       provider = new simpleauthorizationserverprovider(),
       refreshtokenprovider = new simplerefreshtokenprovider()
    };

    activedirectoryfederationservicesbearerauthenticationoptions  adfsauthoptions = new activedirectoryfederationservicesbearerauthenticationoptions()
    {
       metadataendpoint = configurationmanager.appsettings["federationmetadatalocation"]
    };

    app.useoauthauthorizationserver(oauthserveroptions);
    app.useoauthbearerauthentication(new oauthbearerauthenticationoptions());
    app.useactivedirectoryfederationservicesbearerauthentication(adfsauthoptions);
}
```